# Wordpress Visual Composer Template Integration in to Page Template

Tags: php, wordpress, templates, visual-composer

I am using WordPress with the Visual Composer plugin along with the Templatera plugin. I have created a template called footer. Instead of adding the template to every WordPress page (Home, About, Contact Us). Is their any way to create a shortcode to pull the Tempatera template in the Page Attributes Template file?

Answer (score 0):

This is old but like any WordPress shortcode, you can call it directly in the template by doing `<?= do_shortcode('[templatera id="TEMPLATE_ID"]'); ?>`